# ExecuteNonQuery() apply entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

normally database sever side operation.   if i using `ExecuteNonQuery()` returns number of rows affected by an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement.

now i am interested to work with entity framework 
so ! is it possible to apply `ExecuteNonQuery()` method by entity framework .

cause i have to make sure when i use crud operation by entityfarmwork then each operation number of rows affected result showing browser

How can i find out each operation number of row effected

Here is api code for crud operation :

```
// PUT api/Location/5
public IHttpActionResult PutLocation(int id, Location location)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    if (id != location.Id)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    db.Entry(location).State = EntityState.Modified;
    try
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!LocationExists(id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}

// POST api/Location
[ResponseType(typeof(Location))]
public IHttpActionResult PostLocation(Location location)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.Locations.Add(location);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = location.Id }, location);
}

// DELETE api/Location/5
[ResponseType(typeof(Location))]
public IHttpActionResult DeleteLocation(int id)
{
    Location location = db.Locations.Find(id);
    if (location == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    db.Locations.Remove(location);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return Ok(location);
}
```

thank you

Comment: have you tried the same ?

Comment: Can you clarify please ? I have a hard time to read you.

Comment: No! sir , i have no idea how to apply ExecuteNonQuery() by entity framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SaveChanges method  will return count of row that affected

```
using (context c = new Context())
{
      int Count =  c.SaveChanges();
}
```

More information :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792(v=vs.110).aspx